# Chunked arrays in julia

Tags: julia

I found the ChunkedArrays package in Julia as a good idea when dealing with large arrays that can be split into parts especially when multiple threads are used. I tried to install it in Julia 1.8.5 but it seems that is not supported any longer. Is there any package that can deal with large databases that can be split into multiple chunks supported in more recent Julia versions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ChunkSplitters.jl](https://m3g.github.io/ChunkSplitters.jl/stable/). It allows your data array to be split in a loop like

```
for (xrange, ichunk) in chunks(data_array, nchunks, chunk_type)
```

where `nchunks` is the number of chunks to be divided into, and `chunk_type` specifies whether the chunks should be contiguous from the original array (`:batch`) or if the values in a chunk should be taken from different parts of the array (`:scatter`).

(Note that ChunkedArrays, despite the name, isn't about chunking in this sense, but rather about convenient access to buffering and buffered data. It's heavily outdated though, in any case.)